# Excel automated random selection

Tags: excel, random

I have table that has repeated timestamps (multiple records within 1 second). there are a variable number of records within each second; ranging from 1 record to 103 records within a second. I wish to develop a method to select only one random record from all the records with the same timestamp.

The Time column is column A. if possible, i would like the end result of the formula (or macro/VBA) to have the word Keep in column B in the row that was randomly selected. all other non-randomly selected rows can be left blank.

thanks and i apologize if my example data table is not formatted correctly.

```
Time
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:05
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:06
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:07
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:08
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:09
7:51:10
7:51:10
7:51:11
7:51:11
7:51:11
7:51:11
7:51:11
7:51:11
7:51:12
7:51:12
7:51:13
7:51:13
7:51:13
7:51:13
7:51:13
7:51:13
7:51:14
7:51:14
7:51:15
7:51:15
7:51:15
7:51:15
7:51:15
7:51:15
7:51:16
7:51:16
7:51:17
7:51:17
7:51:17
7:51:17
7:51:17
7:51:17
7:51:18
7:51:18
7:51:19
7:51:19
7:51:19
7:51:19
7:51:19
7:51:19
7:51:20
7:51:20
7:51:21
7:51:21
7:51:21
7:51:21
7:51:21
7:51:21
7:51:22
7:51:22
7:51:22
7:51:22
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
7:51:23
```

Comment: time will always be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values will be sorted, the code below should work. You should step through the code to make sure it is working as expected, and once it is, remove the .select statement.  I only tested briefly, so I leave it to you to test more thoroughly.  You can click this link to become [familiar with the RND function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php).

```
Option Explicit
Sub randChoice()
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, t As Integer
stRow = 2
endRow = stRow + 1
While Cells(endRow, 1) <> ""
  Do
    Cells(endRow, 1).Select
    If Cells(stRow, 1) <> Cells(endRow, 1) Then Exit Do
    endRow = endRow + 1
  Loop
  Randomize
  t = Int((endRow - stRow) * rnd)
  Cells(stRow + t, 2) = "Keep"
  stRow = endRow
  endRow = stRow + 1
Wend
End Sub
```